# help in understanding this code snippet

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, gnu-assembler

This is code snipper from header.S file in kernel code. I could not understand what the `lretw` instruction does. I've checked out so many online sources for the instruction.

```
# We will have entered with %cs = %ds+0x20, normalize %cs so
# it is on par with the other segments.
        pushw   %ds 
        pushw   $6f 
        lretw
```

Can any one help me in understanding this instruction?

Comment: http://disi.unitn.it/~abeni/SO2/LinuxKernel/boot.html ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`ret` is the instruction to return from a procedure. So basically it pops the return address from the stack into the EIP register.

the `l` prefix is here to tell that it is a *far* return from procedure. In this case, the instruction first pops a value from the stack into the EIP register and then pops a second value into the CS register.

the `w` suffix is here because at this step we are running in real mode, and operands are 16 bits wide.

The exact code is:

```
    pushw   %ds
    pushw   $6f
    lretw
6:
```

The `6:` is very important here. So what this does is: push the value of ds into the stack, push the adress of the `6` label into the stack, and then trigger this `lretw` instruction. So basically, it will load the address of label `6` into the instruction pointer register, and load the `cs` register with the value of the `ds` register. So this is just a trick to continue the execution at label `6` with a change of the `cs` register value.

You should download http://www.intel.com/design/intarch/manuals/243191.htm which gives precise details for all instructions, including a pseudo-code that details what each instruction is doing.

Comment: i looked in to this manual... but could not find the specific instruction. may be i was not very clear..
you really are awesome thanks for the clear explanation.. i liked it..

Comment: by the way what does the comment mean when it says to normalize %cs... thanks for helping me out.

Comment: why is it $6f? doesnt $6f mean absolute value of 6.. and what does f suffix do ? sorry for the stream of questions.

Comment: No, $6f doesn't mean the absolute value of 6, it means the address of the 6 label being forward (the f stands for forward). See "Local labels" at http://sourceware.org/binutils/docs-2.21/as/Symbol-Names.html#Symbol-Names

Comment: thanks... and sorry for not replying to the best answer.. i was out of sync.

Comment: @ThomasPetazzoni, do you know why we need to normalize %cs to %ds?